# Problem printing Linked List Item in Javascript

Tags: javascript, linked-list, nodes

I want to print all of my linked List item using Javascript. Here I create  Node class for this. But My printlist() method prints undifined. Can any one help me?

Here Is my Code:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
    this.head = null;
  }
  setNextNode(node) {
    this.next = node;
  }

  getNextNode() {
    return this.next;
  }

  printlist() {
    let newhead = this.head;
    let output = " ";
    while (newhead !== null) {
      output += newhead.data + ' ';
      console.log(output);
      newhead = newhead.getNextNode(this.next);
    }
  }
}

const n1 = new Node(1);
const n2 = new Node(2);
const n3 = new Node(3);
n1.next = n2;
n2.next = n3;
//console.log(n1);
console.log(n1.printlist());
```

Comment: printlist does not return anything

Comment: @epascarello - it doesn't, you're right, so `console.log`-ing its return value is pointless. But it has `console.log` statements inside it.

Comment: Did you mean to do `while (newhead === null) {` it will never do into the loop since head is null.

Comment: anyway, the reason it doesn't print is because it never enters the loop, because nowhere in your class to you set `this.head` to a non-null value!

Comment: Why does the `Node` class have a `head` property? That should be a property of the `LinkedList` class.

Comment: @epascarello thanks. But console.log should print.

Answer (score 1):

in your constructor, you should set a value for **this.head** (something like **this** or **this.next**).

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
    this.head = this;
  }
  setNextNode(node) {
    this.next = node;
  }

  getNextNode() {
    return this.next;
  }

  printlist() {
    let newhead = this.head;
    let output = " ";
    while (newhead !== null) {
      output += newhead.data + ' ';
      console.log(output);
      newhead = newhead.getNextNode(this.next);
    }
  }
}

const n1 = new Node(1);
const n2 = new Node(2);
const n3 = new Node(3);
n1.next = n2;
n2.next = n3;
//console.log(n1);
console.log(n1.printlist());
```

Comment: @ Reza Zand this is working. but what this.head = this means? is it denote constructor?

Comment: @BarunBepart "this" refers to the current object you want to print all items linked to. For this example, it is "n1".

Comment: @ Reza Zand then how to insert at middle of the list?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your node's `head` reference is `null`, so the loop in `printList` will not loop.

The concept of *head* is not one that belongs to the Node class, but to a container class. It is a reference to a *first* node, so it shouldn't be a property of every node.

I would also not have a `printList` method, but make the list iterable. That way it becomes much more flexible, and printing becomes very easy for the caller.

Here is how to do that:

```js
class Node {
  constructor(data, next=null) { // Allow optional argument
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
    // No head property here
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null; // Here we want a head reference
  }

  prepend(data) {
    this.head = new Node(data, this.head);
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator]() { // Make a list iterable
    let node = this.head;
    while (node) {
      yield node.data;
      node = node.next;
    }
  }
}

const list = new LinkedList();
list.prepend(3);
list.prepend(2);
list.prepend(1);
console.log(...list);  // This will call the iterator method
```

Comment: Good Way!! What does the Prepend method do and *[Symbol.iterator]?

Comment: `prepend` inserts a new node at the start of the list. So the previous head is used as value for the new node's `next` reference. `*[Symbol.iterator]` makes the instance iterable. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator). This method is a generator (cf. asterisk) and gets called when trying to iterate an instance. It is what in the last `console.log` is happening with the spread syntax.

Comment: if i want to insert item middle of the list how can i do this? my code:   `addToHead(data){
        let new_head= new Node(data);
        new_head.next=this.head;
        this.head=new_head;
    }
  //1.2:insert a node after a given node
   insertAfter(prevnode, data){
    if(prevnode == null){
        console.log("Previous cannot be Null");
        return;
    }
    let new_node = new Node(data);
     new_node.next=prevnode;
     prevnode.next=new_node;
   }`

Comment: thanks for your advice. I wanted to know how to insert node into middle of linkedlist?

Comment: I understand, but can you post it as a new question? The comment section is not intended for follow up questions. Use the "Ask Question" button, but first make sure that (1) you have searched that this question has not been asked before (2) you show your attempt and explain where it goes wrong.

Comment: In the mean time, can you confirm whether my answer here answers to your question at the top, i.e. about printing the list?